Does $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$ contain a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$?
My question is already in the title. Let $\mathbb{R}$ be considered with its structure of additive group.
Does the quotient group  $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$ contain a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ itself?
My intuition says: absolutely no! But I have no proof, so any help is welcome.
Thank you very much for your attention.

Yes, it does, try to prove it.

The first way I can think to show it is uses a result requiring the axiom of choice. It would not be constructive, then.

If your intuition is like mine, you may be accidentally including some topological or order structure in your mental image of $\Bbb R$ which is not present in the additive group. Remembering that $\Bbb R$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb Q$ helps correct this.

I apologize: my intuition was badly wrong!

Good that you "guys" have memorized this!

Consider that $\mathbb{R}$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. By Zorn's Lemma, we can extend $\{1\}$ to an basis $B$. Because $B$ is infinite, there exists a injective function $f : B \to B$ that does not have $1$ in its image, so we can extend $f$ to an injective linear function $F : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ whose image is orthogonal to $\mathbb{Q}$. Thus, the composition of $F$ with $\pi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$ is an injective homomorphism, i.e. an isomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ to a subgroup of $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$.

Dear Levi, thank you very very much for having given such a nice solution to my problem. I see you are new here, and I welcome you warmly! I hope you will share your insights with all of us as today.

$\mathbb{R}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space, say $\mathbb{R}\simeq \bigoplus\mathbb{Q}$. The number of summands is necessarily infinite (for example by comparing cardinalities). And we can choose basis so that $1$ belongs to one of the summands. Which shows that
$$\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\simeq \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{R}$$
So not only it contains a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ but even a direct summand.
Note that $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is topologically a circle. And so a circle contains $\mathbb{R}$ as its direct summand. Which even today sounds very counterintuitive to me. Of course the above isomorphism is algebraic only, it is not continuous. In fact the circle does not have a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ as topological groups: the only two connected subgroups of the circle are the trivial group and circle itself.

Thank you very very ... much for having be so nice to take some time to answer my question. Your remarks are really very very interesting!

I add here some details to the solution given by @freakish. Extend ${ 1 }$ to a Hamel basis $\mathcal{B}$ of the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space $\mathbb{R}$, and note that since $\mathcal{B}$ is infinite, there exists a bijection $f:\mathcal{B} \rightarrow \mathcal{B} \backslash { 1 }$. Extend $f$ to a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear map $F:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and note that by construction $\mathbb{R}$ is the direct sum of the linear subspaces $\mathbb{Q}$ and $F(\mathbb{R})$. Now let $p:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ be the canonical projection and set $G=p \circ F$.

$G:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ turns out to be an injective group homomorphism, so that the additive group $\mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to the subgroup $G(\mathbb{R})$ of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. Moreover, by construction we get $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}+G(\mathbb{R})$ and $(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})\cap G(\mathbb{R})=\emptyset$. So $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of its subgroups $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ and $G(\mathbb{R})$. But $G(\mathbb{R})\simeq\mathbb{R}$, so we get $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\simeq\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{R}$.
